# How to increase the size of a PDF without affecting its contents

Tags: pdf

A website is asking me to upload a pay stub as proof of identity, and the only stubs I have available are text-only PDFs of about 2KB. Unfortunately, this site only accepts files between 10KB and 5MB. Is there an easy way to increase the size of a file up to 10KB without making it appear as though it has been tampered with?

Comment: Will they accept a scan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you zoom in on the PDF and do a screen capture and upload as PNG or GIF, or even bitmap, the file size will be larger.

Answer (score 0):

PDF files are *mostly* textual (with the exception of streams and other binary components they can contain.

PDF file format also support comments, defined as any line which it's first character is the `#` hash/pound sign. If you open a PDF file with any text editor you'll also notice this is also how the header magic is defined.

At the end of a PDF file there's a cross reference table to all (or most) objects within the pdf. It is expected to be found at the end by most PDF parsers, and since it has offsets in character count from the file beginning, adding comments will most likely break the file. Most readers however will ignore lines starting with a hash sign at the end of the file. You could therefore just add a huge-ass line of whatever your favorite character is.

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained how a use could  edit a PDF to add such a comment line.

Comment: I believe I did. Simply by opening the file with your favorite text editor.